# How can i make writes to a gzip file from my perl script non-blocking?

Tags: perl, nonblocking

I'm currently writing a script that takes a database as input and generates all valid combinations from the 10+ tables, following certain rules. Since the output is pretty darn huge, i'm dumping this through gzip into the file, like this:

```
open( my $OUT, '|-', "gzip > file" );
for ( @data ) {
    my $line = calculate($_);
    print $OUT $line;
}
```

Due to the nature of the beast though i end up having to make hundreds of thousands of small writes, one for each line. This means that between each calculation it waits for gzip to receive the data and get done compressing it. At least i think so, i might be wrong.

In case I'm right though, I'm wondering how i can make this print asynchronous, i.e. it fires the data at gzip and then goes on processing the data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pipes already use a buffer so that the writing program doesn't have to wait for the reading program.  However, that buffer is usually fairly small (it's normally only 64KB on Linux) and not easily changed (it requires recompiling the kernel). If the standard buffer is not enough, the easiest thing to do is include a buffering program in the pipeline:

```
open( my $OUT, '|-', "bfr | gzip > file" );
```

[bfr](http://www.glines.org/software/bfr) simply reads STDIN into an in-memory buffer, and writes to STDOUT as fast as the next program allows.  The default is a 5MB buffer, but you can change that with the `-b` option (e.g. `bfr -b10m` for a 10MB buffer).

Comment: Thanks for that! I'm not anywhere near that buffer, with a single line piped to gzip being 850 bytes long. :)

Answer (score 4):

Give [`IO::Compress::Gzip`](http://p3rl.org/IO%3a%3aCompress%3a%3aGzip) a try. It accepts a [filehandle](http://p3rl.org/IO%3a%3aCompress%3a%3aGzip#Constructor) to write to. You can [set `O_NONBLOCK`](http://p3rl.org/opentut#Open-agrave-la-C) on that filehandle.

Comment: Doing the compression within Perl is basically the exact opposite of what i want i'm afraid. the O_NONBLOCK thing is interesting though. I just don't know if i can apply it to a pipe to another process.

Comment: The last time I benchmarked it, using IO::Compress::Gzip was significantly slower than spawning a `gzip` process.

Answer (score 1):

naturally i'll will do it in a thread or with a fork as you wish.
http://hell.jedicoder.net/?p=82

Comment: "thread" No. Not in Perl. Trying to use threads in Perl only leads to doom and tears. Fork would be an option if it wouldn't break my debugger (and i wasn't on Windows).

Comment: eads to doom and tears : i'll remember it :) (i never used it)

Comment: another solution for me (but not under windows) was to make something like system("gzip - $line &");

Comment: That seems rather dangerous since it'd mean spawning a gzip instance for each line written and having them append to the same file, meaning they could easily run into issues where they overwrite or interleave each other's output. Also, since this is pure IO i imagine there'd be ways to do this without abusing the OSes process creation capabilities. ;)

Comment: i hope so :). Moreover the "system" call is probably more expensive than the gzip line.

Comment: But maybe it's the fastest way by doing the way you've done, 'cause you can write only once on the disk, so if the call is fast, the writing will not be faster enough.